# Adjust exponent text after setting scientific limits on matplotlib axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

At the moment if I set matplotlib y axis ticklabels to scientific mode it gives me an exponent at the top of the y axis of the form `1e-5`

I'd like to adjust this to read `r'$\mathregular{10^{-5}}$'` so that it prints out nicely.

Here's my example code:

```
# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot 100 random points 
# the y values of which are very small
ax.scatter(np.random.rand(100), np.random.rand(100)/100000.0)

# Set the y limits appropriately
ax.set_ylim(0, 1/100000.0)

# Change the y ticklabel format to scientific format
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(-2, 2))

# Get the offset value
offset = ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()

# Print it out
print '1st offset printout: {}'.format(offset)

# Run plt.tight_layout()
plt.tight_layout()

# Print out offset again - you can see the value now!
print '2nd offset printout: {}'.format(offset)

# Change it to latex format
offset.set_text(r'$\mathregular{10^{-5}}$')

# Print it out
print '3rd offset printout: {}'.format(offset)

# Add some text to the middle of the figure just to 
# check that it isn't the latex format that's the problem
ax.text(0.5, 0.5/100000.0, r'$\mathregular{10^{-2}}$')

# And show the figure
plt.show()
```

My output looks like this:

```
1st offset printout: Text(0,0.5,u'')
2nd offset printout: Text(0,636.933,u'1e\u22125')
3rd offset printout: Text(0,636.933,u'$\\mathregular{10^{-5}}$')
```

[image]

You can find the code and output figure [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/HappyPenguin/9718c2031413c227200d).

There are two oddities: One is that I can't overwrite the 1e-5 at the top of the y axis (which is the goal), and the other is that I have to run `plt.tight_layout()` in order to even see that unicode value as the offset.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

EDIT: The original question didn't make clear that I'd like to automatically detect the exponent as is currently calculated by `ticklabel_format`. So instead of passing a set string to the offset text it should automatically detect that value and adjust the latex string accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on @edsmith's answer one possible work around which does what I'd like is to get the offset text, convert it to a latex string, turn off the offset and add in that string at the top of the axis.

```
def format_exponent(ax, axis='y'):

    # Change the ticklabel format to scientific format
    ax.ticklabel_format(axis=axis, style='sci', scilimits=(-2, 2))

    # Get the appropriate axis
    if axis == 'y':
        ax_axis = ax.yaxis
        x_pos = 0.0
        y_pos = 1.0
        horizontalalignment='left'
        verticalalignment='bottom'
    else:
        ax_axis = ax.xaxis
        x_pos = 1.0
        y_pos = -0.05
        horizontalalignment='right'
        verticalalignment='top'

    # Run plt.tight_layout() because otherwise the offset text doesn't update
    plt.tight_layout()
    ##### THIS IS A BUG 
    ##### Well, at least it's sub-optimal because you might not
    ##### want to use tight_layout(). If anyone has a better way of 
    ##### ensuring the offset text is updated appropriately
    ##### please comment!

    # Get the offset value
    offset = ax_axis.get_offset_text().get_text()

    if len(offset) > 0:
        # Get that exponent value and change it into latex format
        minus_sign = u'\u2212'
        expo = np.float(offset.replace(minus_sign, '-').split('e')[-1])
        offset_text = r'x$\mathregular{10^{%d}}$' %expo

        # Turn off the offset text that's calculated automatically
        ax_axis.offsetText.set_visible(False)

        # Add in a text box at the top of the y axis
        ax.text(x_pos, y_pos, offset_text, transform=ax.transAxes,
               horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment,
               verticalalignment=verticalalignment)
    return ax
```

Note that you should be able to use the position of the offset text by calling `pos = ax_axis.get_offset_text().get_position()` but these values are not in axis units (they're likely pixel units - thanks @EdSmith - and thus not very helpful). Therefore I've just set the `x_pos` and `y_pos` values according to whichever axis we're looking at.

I also wrote a little function to automatically detect appropriate x and y limits (even though I know that matplotlib has lots of fancy ways of doing this).

```
def get_min_max(x, pad=0.05):
    '''
    Find min and max values such that
    all the data lies within 90% of
    of the axis range
    '''
    r = np.max(x) - np.min(x)
    x_min = np.min(x) - pad * r
    x_max = np.max(x) + pad * r
    return x_min, x_max
```

So, to update my example from the question (with a slight change to make both axes need the exponent):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot 100 random points that are very small
x = np.random.rand(100)/100000.0
y = np.random.rand(100)/100000.0
ax.scatter(x, y)

# Set the x and y limits
x_min, x_max = get_min_max(x)
ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)
y_min, y_max = get_min_max(y)    
ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)

# Format the exponents nicely
ax = format_exponent(ax, axis='x')
ax = format_exponent(ax, axis='y')

# And show the figure
plt.show()
```

[image]

A gist with an ipython notebook showing the output of the code is available [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/HappyPenguin/85d4483bfc686bdbd52b).

I hope that helps!

Comment: Very neat. I assume this is a bug in matplotlib as you should be able to replace the `offsettext` string directly. Your description is a little confusing -- you don't add in that string but turn off `offsettext` and put the latex label in the same place.  Ideally the replacement text would be based on the location of `ax_axis.get_offset_text().get_position()`. I couldn't find a way to do this as `pos` is in pixel units (I think), did you?

Comment: You're right - I'll edit my reference to `pos` in the answer now. I couldn't figure out what to do with those numbers (in fact - it didn't occur to me that they were pixel coordinates - good guess!).

Do you have any suggestions on how to get the values to update without doing plt.tight_layout()?

Comment: @KirstieJane I would like to point out that I had a similar question, and just now found a [slightly better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468524/5472354).

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `plt.ticklabel_format` does not work correctly. However if you define the ScalarFormatter yourself *and* set the limits for scientific notation to the formatter, you can get the offset automatically in the mathtext format like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker

x = np.linspace(3,5)
y = np.sin(np.linspace(0,6*np.pi))*1e5

plt.plot(x,y)

mf = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
mf.set_powerlimits((-2,2))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mf)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You get `offset` and set the text value but there doesn't seem to be a way to actually apply this to the axis... Even calling `ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_text(offset)` doesn't update the offset displayed. A work around it to remove the offset text and replace with brackets on the axis label,

```
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylabel("datalabel " +  r'$\left(\mathregular{10^{-5}}\right)$')
```

Or replace it with a manual text box, as a minimal example,

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)

# Plot 100 random points 
# the y values of which are very small
large = 100000.0
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)/large

ax.scatter(x,y)

# Set the y limits appropriately
ax.set_ylim(0, 1/large)

# Change the y ticklabel format to scientific format
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(-2, 2))

#print(ax.yaxis.offsetText.get_position())
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax.text(-0.21, 1.01/large, r'$\mathregular{10^{-2}}$')

# And show the figure
plt.show()
```

I know this isn't ideal but it may be that offset text cannot be changed manually or can only be the consistent with the numerical values...

Comment: Thanks for your answer - there's something very similar at this [blog post](https://alexpearce.me/2014/04/exponent-label-in-matplotlib). It is a work around but it misses out the fact that the `ticklabel_format` method figures out the exponent for you and I feel like that should be something I can get from the `offsetText`. I'm going to adjust my question to try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines in your code

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ptick
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ptick.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [@KirstieJane's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522781/5472354), I found a sightly better way, wich also works without having to call `tight_layout`, and in particular, also works for figures using `constrained_layout`. Calling `ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)` is all that is necessary for setting the text. Here is an MWE:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tight_layout import get_renderer
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import \
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
# from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
# from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QGridLayout


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(canvas)
        self.setLayout(lay)

        image = np.random.uniform(10000000, 100000000, (100, 100))
        image_artist = ax.imshow(image)
        colorbar = fig.colorbar(image_artist)
        colorbar.ax.ticklabel_format()
        renderer = get_renderer(fig)
        colorbar.ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)
        colorbar.ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
        offset_text = colorbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()
        exp = offset_text.get_text().split('e')[1].replace('+', '')
        colorbar.ax.set_ylabel(rf'Parameter [U${{\times}}10^{{{exp}}}$]')

        canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

For a thorough discussion of the solution, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62468524/5472354).