# change scientific notation abbreviation of y axis units to a string

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6

First I would like to apologize as I know I am not asking this question correctly (which is why I cant find what is likely a simple answer).

I have a graph[image: graph]

As you can see above the y axis it says 1e11 meaning that the units are in 100 Billions. I would like to change the graph to read 100 Billion instead of 1e11.

I am not sure what such a notation is called.

To be clear I am not asking to change the whole y axis to number values like other questions I only want to change the top 1e11 to be more readable to those who are less mathematical.

```
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```

results in [image] an undesired result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi May be this can help. Or this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855363/how-to-remove-relative-shift-in-matplotlib-axis/11858063#11858063

Comment: Those solutions are related but different to what i am looking for

Comment: @Scott Boston  My question is different please unmark as duplicate

Comment: @KevinRiorda Okay, sorry I have reopened the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31517156/588071

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def billions(x, pos):
    return '$%1.1fB' % (x*1e-9)

formatter = FuncFormatter(billions)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

located from https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html

produces [image]

Comment: You beat me to it. :) +1

Comment: Did not know matplotlib had it. +1.