# Is there a way to incorporate the extra artist generated by axes.ticklabel_format() into the axis label instead?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In short, instead of the version on the left, I would like the version on the right. Is there any way to do this without having to draw the figure fist? You can access the artist before, but at that point, the text is not set.

[image] [image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text


image = np.random.uniform(10000000, 100000000, (100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
image_artist = ax.imshow(image)
colorbar = fig.colorbar(image_artist)
colorbar.ax.ticklabel_format()

fig.show()

for artist in colorbar.ax.yaxis.get_children():
    if isinstance(artist, Text) and artist.get_text():
        exp = artist.get_text().split('e')[1].replace('+', '')
        colorbar.ax.set_ylabel(rf'Parameter [U${{\times}}10^{{{exp}}}$]')
        artist.set_visible(False)

fig.show()
```

Comment: You can access the offset text via [`get_offset_text()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_offset_text.html)

Comment: See also [Adjust exponent text after setting scientific limits on matplotlib axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517156/adjust-exponent-text-after-setting-scientific-limits-on-matplotlib-axis).  There `plt.tight_layout()`is suggested to force filling in the offset_text. Thereafter, you get the desired artist as `offset_text = colorbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()`

Comment: Great, this is basically what I was looking for. Such a shame though that these things are so badly documented. How are you supposed to know that the extra text generated by `ticklabel_format` is passed to the `offset_text`? Anyways.. do you have any idea on how to do this if you use `constrained_layout=True`?

Comment: You could also just divide your data by 10^6 or 10^7 before plotting, and then not worry about the offset text but just add that information to your label.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBrodersen, I thought about that as well, but unfortunately, I don't know the order of magnitude, and it is very hard to determine, since in the case of a `colorbar`, it is directly dependent on the `clim` of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get any of the tick values until you trigger a draw, because ticks are evaluated lazily.  So if you need information from the locators and formatters, you must call `fig.canvas.draw()`.  Everything above about `tight_layout` is a red herring because it all calls `fig.canvas.draw()`.

As for your actual request, this still calls `fig.canvas.draw` but that's just for the convenience of getting the exponent the formatter uses.  You could easily get that yourself from the vlim values.  Otherwise, this just sets the offset text to be blank rather than making a scientific notation label.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

class NoOffsetFormatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def get_offset(self):
        return ''

formatter = NoOffsetFormatter()

image = np.random.uniform(10000000, 100000000, (100, 100))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
image_artist = ax.imshow(image)
colorbar = fig.colorbar(image_artist)
colorbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
fig.canvas.draw()
exp = formatter.orderOfMagnitude
colorbar.ax.set_ylabel(rf'Parameter [U${{\times}}10^{{{exp}}}$]')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "You could easily get that yourself from the vlim values."? I mean, in the end, that's what I want. So you are saying there is a way to get the order of magnitiude without having to draw the figure? Drawing the figure can be quite expensive, and I want to aviod it as much as possible, additionally so because I am using a canvas embedded in a PyQt UI, and I don't to 'update' the canvas at a point where it is not ready to be seen yet.

Comment: Sure you could just call the locator manually or copy the code that figures out the order of magnitude.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the locator? I've encountered this term quite a few times now, but I have never figured out what it is.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

Comment: Thanks! I know this is getting off-topic, but those locators are different from [these guys](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_axes_locator.html) yes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I followed the clue pointed out by @JohanC in the comments that you could use `fig.tight_layout()` in order to 'trick' the figure into setting the text of the `offset_text` artist without having to draw the figure. The `offset_text` artist is being used by the `ax.ticklabel_format()` method to display the order of magnitude (again, as pointed out by @JohanC in the comments). This trick is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31517156/5472354) which is similar to mine, and seems to be a fair enough solution for most cases. However what if you don't want to use `tight_layout`, or even worse, you are using the incompatible `constrained_layout` instead (such as myself)?

### Summary:

So I did a lot of digging through the matplotlib source code following the trace of `tight_layout`, and fortunately, I was successful. In short, a universal solution to this problem is to call `ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)`, where `renderer` is the renderer of the figure. It should also be less expensive. The following MWE shows that this works even when using `constrained_layout`:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.tight_layout import get_renderer
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import \
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
# from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
# from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QGridLayout


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(canvas)
        self.setLayout(lay)

        image = np.random.uniform(10000000, 100000000, (100, 100))
        image_artist = ax.imshow(image)
        colorbar = fig.colorbar(image_artist)
        colorbar.ax.ticklabel_format()
        renderer = get_renderer(fig)
        colorbar.ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)
        colorbar.ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
        offset_text = colorbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()
        exp = offset_text.get_text().split('e')[1].replace('+', '')
        colorbar.ax.set_ylabel(rf'Parameter [U${{\times}}10^{{{exp}}}$]')

        canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Step by step explanation:

Here is what I did:

- I looked at the `tight_layout` [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/_modules/matplotlib/figure.html#Figure.tight_layout). Via elimination, I realized that the important bit for this trick to work was the following statement,

  > ```
  > kwargs = get_tight_layout_figure(
  >       self, self.axes, subplotspec_list, renderer,
  >       pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  > ```

  which is great, because I also realized the the statement that 'essentially' makes `tight_layout` incompatible with `constrained_layout` is the call to `subplots_adjust(**kwargs)`.
- Then I looked at the `get_tight_layout_figure` [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/tight_layout.html#get_tight_layout_figure). In order for this to have any effect on a `colorbar`, you need to use a workaround, since by default, the `colorbar` is added via a basic `Axes` instance, and not via an `AxesSubplot` instance. This is an important difference, because `get_tight_layout_figure` requires the `subplotspec_list`, which in turn is generated by [`get_subplotspec_list`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/tight_layout.html#get_subplotspec_list). The latter returns `None` in case of the `colorbar.ax` though, because, while an `AxesSubplot` instance comes with a `locator`, a regular `Axes` instance does not. The `locator` is what is being used in `get_subplotspec_list` to return the `subplotspec`. The workaround is then to use the approach described at the bottom [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html#colorbar), by making the colorbar axes locatable:

  > ```
  > from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
  >
  > arr = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
  > fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
  > im = plt.imshow(arr, interpolation="none")
  >
  > divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
  > cax = divider.append_axes("right", "5%", pad="3%")
  > plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
  >
  > plt.tight_layout()
  > ```
- With this, I was able to run the `get_tight_layout_figure` on my `colorbar.ax`:

  > ```
  > from matplotlib.tight_layout import get_renderer, get_tight_layout_figure
  > renderer = get_renderer(fig)
  > gridspec = colorbar.ax.get_axes_locator().get_subplotspec()
  > get_tight_layout_figure(fig, [colorbar.ax], [gridspec], renderer)
  > ```
- Again via elimination, I realized that the important statement in  `get_tight_layout_figure` for the trick to work, was this statement:

  > ```
  > kwargs = auto_adjust_subplotpars(fig, renderer,
  >                                nrows_ncols=(max_nrows, max_ncols),
  >                                num1num2_list=num1num2_list,
  >                                subplot_list=subplot_list,
  >                                ax_bbox_list=ax_bbox_list,
  >                                pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  > ```

  This made things a lot easier again, because for this function, you only need the `fig` and `renderer`, as well as `nrows_ncols`, `num1num2_list` and `subplot_list`. The latter three arguments are luckyly easy enough to obtain / simulate, where `nrows_ncols` and `num1num2_list` are lists of numbers, in this simple case `(1, 1)` and `[(0, 0)]` respectively, and `subplot_list` only contains the `colorbar.ax`. What's more, the workaround introduced above doesn't really work with `constrained_laout`, since part of the colorbar axes (in particular the label which all of this is about) can be cut off:

  [image]
- So then, you guessed it, I looked into the `auto_adjust_subplotpars` [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/tight_layout.html#auto_adjust_subplotpars). And again, via elimination, I this time quickly found the relevant line of code:

  > ```
  > tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots
  >                         if ax.get_visible()])
  > ```

  The important part here is of course `ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)`, as you can tell by my solution. This is as far as I could trace it, though I do believe that it should be possible to go even a little bit further. It was actually not that easy to find the relevant sour code for the `get_tightbbox`-method, because even though the code suggests that what is being called is `Axes.get_tightbbox`, which at least can also be found in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_tightbbox.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_tightbbox) (although there is no link to the source code), what is *actually* being used is the `Artist.get_tightbbox`, of which, for some reason, there is [no documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/artist_api.html), however it does exist in the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/_modules/matplotlib/artist.html#Artist). I extracted it and made my own 'detached' version, to see if I could go even deeper:

  > ```
  > from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
  >
  > def get_tightbbox(artist, renderer):
  >     """
  >     Like `Artist.get_window_extent`, but includes any clipping.
  >
  >     Parameters
  >     ----------
  >     renderer : `.RendererBase` instance
  >         renderer that will be used to draw the figures (i.e.
  >         ``fig.canvas.get_renderer()``)
  >
  >     Returns
  >     -------
  >     bbox : `.BBox`
  >         The enclosing bounding box (in figure pixel co-ordinates).
  >     """
  >     bbox = artist.get_window_extent(renderer)
  >     if artist.get_clip_on():
  >         clip_box = artist.get_clip_box()
  >         if clip_box is not None:
  >             bbox = Bbox.intersection(bbox, clip_box)
  >         clip_path = artist.get_clip_path()
  >         if clip_path is not None and bbox is not None:
  >             clip_path = clip_path.get_fully_transformed_path()
  >             bbox = Bbox.intersection(bbox, clip_path.get_extents())
  >
  >     return bbox
  > ```

  But here, something very curious happened, which I cannot explain, and ultimately stopped me from further investigation:

> running `get_tightbbox(colorbar.ax, renderer)` is **not** the same as running `colorbar.ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)`!

I have no idea why. Running `get_tightbbox(colorbar.ax, renderer)`, `get_tightbbox` is only executed once (as you would assume), but running `colorbar.ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)`, it runs several times, for a bunch, but not all, of the `colorbar.ax`'s children. I tried to emulate it but looping over the children and run `get_tightbbox` individually for each (in particular I tested this on the `offset_text` artist of course), but it didn't have the same effect. It does **not** work. So for now, `colorbar.ax.get_tightbbox(renderer)` is the way to go.

Comment: Using tight layout *does* draw the figure using fig.canvas.draw.   That’s how it knows how large everything will be. You may as well call that yourself.   

That said, you could pretty easily get what you want by writing a new formatter that just doesn’t pass the exponent to the offset text.

Comment: Oh no, all this work for nothing :( but thanks for letting me know!