# How to prevent scientific notation in the axis offset in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot where the y-axis offset is `5.223e1`.  I'd rather have it just say `52.23`.  Can this be done?

Unlike this question: [prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot), I am interested in removing the scientific notation from the offset itself, not the entire axis label.  I want to keep the offset, just not have it be in scientific notation.

Comment: [Seems similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number).

Comment: ^ Though there are many answers there that apparently think the question was about turning the offset off, instead of keeping it and just changing the format.

Comment: [Also similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517156/adjust-exponent-text-after-setting-scientific-limits-on-matplotlib-axis).

Answer (score 2):

I think this can only be done by subclassing and defining your own [formatting function](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c39ba912786a2c430e78f39c1375c71715ae94ad/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L738).
Minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

class my_ScalarFormatter(ScalarFormatter):
    def format_data(self, value):
        return f'{value:.2f}'

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(my_ScalarFormatter())
ax1.set_ylim(52.23, 52.231)
ax2.set_ylim(52.23, 52.231)
ax1.set_title('Default Formatter')
ax2.set_title('Custom Formatter')
plt.show()
```

[image]