# Update text in matplotlib through the Artist

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to be able to freely change a matplotlib plot. I'm doing this by finding the `Artist` objects in a plot (which are responsible for drawing everything) but I can't update the text.

For example, here I attempt to change the magnitude text. I can update the color and position but not the text like I want to.
[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make the plot
data = [1e6 + i for i in range(10)]
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(data)
plt.title("Normal")
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(data)
plt.title("Updated Artist")
plt.draw()

# Find all `Text` Artist objects in the current axis
t = plt.gca().findobj(plt.Text)

# Filter them to get the one with the text we want
t = next(filter(lambda x: x.get_text() == '+1e6', t))

# Update the position
pos = t.get_position()
pos = (pos[0]+0.1, pos[1])
t.set_position(pos)

# Set properties
t.set_text('1,000,000') # This doesn't work! :( 
t.set_color('red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your question? where is `Artist`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll make that clearer. `Artist` is the baseclass matplotlib uses to display items (lines, text, etc), so the artist I'm looking is the text element with the magnitude (eg. the one that turns red in the plot).

Comment: If it's useful: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/artist_api.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's intended or a longstanding bug, but `set_text()` has not worked for the `offsetText` at least [since 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31517156/13138364).

You can hide the `offsetText` and then add your custom label with [`Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html):

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
ax1.plot(data)
ax1.set_title('Normal')
ax2.plot(data)
ax2.set_title('Updated Artist')

ax2.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax2.text(-0.4, max(data)+0.6, '1,000,000', color='r', size='small')
```

[image: manual sci notation label]

---

---

To get the text coords programmatically, it seems some weird workarounds are needed.

Theoretically we should be able to use `get_position()` with `get_transform()`, but this always places the text at `(0, 0.5)`:

```py
# does not work
x, y = ax2.yaxis.offsetText.get_position()
transform = ax2.yaxis.offsetText.get_transform()
ax2.text(x, y, '1,000,000', transform=transform)
```

If we first force a canvas redraw, it places the text at `(0, 345.952885)` which is closer but still not correct:

```py
# still does not work
plt.draw()
x, y = ax2.yaxis.offsetText.get_position()
transform = ax2.yaxis.offsetText.get_transform()
ax2.text(x, y, '1,000,000', transform=transform)
```

So the only way I could get this to work is:

1. Run the plot once
2. Get the coords manually *after* the plot has run once:

   ```py
   ax2.yaxis.offsetText.get_position()

   # (0, 301.55984375)
   ```
3. Go back and fill in the coords:

   ```py
   ax2.text(0, 301.55984375, '1,000,000', transform=ax2.yaxis.offsetText.get_transform())
   ```

Comment: Neat! re:set_text that's good to know (and very odd). Is there a way to set the new text's position based on the old text? It seems like there's going to be some guesswork involved otherwise

Comment: @Alter see if the update makes sense and works for you. the whole thing is a bit weird

Comment: I ran into the same issue with`plt.draw()`... very weird. Didn't realize it would change again after `plt.show()`. I'm kind of surprised matplotlib can be this difficult to work with, thanks for figuring out my messy problem.